A British movie about sexual confessions
I'm looking for a 2000's movie in which 4-5 young close friends ( all women ) gather together in a living room at one of their apartments at night and telling each other their past experiences until morning. It was made in England, most likely London. They were all attractive, young, aged between 25 - 35. They were completely different in physical appearance, like blonde, brunette, black, Indian etc. 
The movie continues with 10-15 mins stories of each other. I remember the story of the British-Indian girl. She was working in an office, in a large private company. One day an office boy gave her a delivery. There was a rose, a small binocular and a note written just a word 'look'. She picked up the binocular and saw a guy in an elevator outside of the building opposite to the building which she works. He was either a worker or a window cleaner. He was holding a sign which was written like 'Meet me at lunch'. 
She waited the lunch break and go to the other building. The guy was waiting down there. His friends applause and congratulated him when they saw her. He started the elevator and they went up. Then they ate a picnic food which he prepared and drank a red wine. They had a conversation like this:  

Girl: I'm so surprised. I don't know what to say.
Boy: I love you. I want to be with you. 
Girl: What? I don't even know you.
Boy: Ok. What do you want to know about me?  
Girl: For example, how old are you?
Boy: Old enough to buy my own drink at a bar. We can talk about each other for hours, days but we lose lots of time.

After a couple of mins talking, they made love on the small outdoor lift. She was telling the details to her friends passionately and emotionally. Her friends were jealous of that. They all shared their stories in order. Unfortunately, I couldn't remember much of the other stories and how did it end. 
